# Eclipse CDT is reporting false erros while using std::index_sequence

Tags: c++17, eclipse-cdt

***UPDATED: Added complete example and compiler information***

I have Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0) with CDT 9.7.0.20190309 and the build-in compiler reports false positive errors while using std::index_sequence in C++17:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

class Sample {
public:
    template<std::size_t N >
    std::size_t get_percentage( void ) {
        return N;
    }

    template<std::size_t... Is>
    inline std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(Is)> calculate_percentages( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) noexcept {
        return { this->get_percentage<Is>()... };
    }
    template<std::size_t N>
    inline std::array<std::size_t, N> get_percentages( void ) noexcept {
        return this->calculate_percentages( std::make_index_sequence<N>() );
    /*           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::array calculate_percentages(std::integer_sequence) ' */
    }
};

TEST( IntegerSequence, InvalidArgumentsError ) {
    Sample test;
    std::array<std::size_t, 5> data = test.get_percentages<5>();
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

But the normal compilation succeeds without any problem.

My **CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings** in 
Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers is as follows:

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++17 "${INPUTS}"
```

The same applies for **CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings**.

Rebuilding the index does not helped in there.

The GCC version I am using:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help...

Comment: Please post a complete code example. (Your use of `this->` suggests that this code occurs at class scope, but there is no class declaration in your code.)

Comment: Also, CDT's ability to understand standard library code like `std::index_sequence` will depend on which standard library version you're using, which in turn is usually coupled to the compiler version, so please state what compiler version you're using.

Comment: @HC4-reinstateMonica I have added a complete example where Eclipse is reporting the same problem. Compiler version has been publiched as well.

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce the problem now. It seems to be related to the fact that newer versions of gcc's standard library use a compiler intrinsic called `__integer_pack` in their implementation of `std::index_sequence`, which Eclipse CDT does not understand.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fact the bug has now been fixed in Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the standard library that comes with gcc 8 and newer uses a new compiler intrinsic called `__integer_pack` to implement `std::make_integer_sequence` (and related utilities like `std::make_index_sequence`).

Eclipse CDT's parser does not currently understand the `__integer_pack` intrinsic, and therefore it has trouble correctly parsing code that uses `std::make_integer_sequence` / `std::make_index_sequence` with these newer gcc versions.

I [filed a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=553794) to track adding support for the `__integer_pack` intrinsic.

Meanwhile, a workaround you could employ is to use gcc 7 or older. If you need gcc 8 or newer to actually build your code, you could still tell Eclipse the look at the standard library headers of e.g. gcc 7 by replacing `${COMMAND}` in the mentioned "built-in compiler settings" configuration with `g++-7`.

**UPDATE**: The Eclipse bug is now fixed, with the fix targeting CDT's 9.11 release (scheduled to be part Eclipse 2020-03).